# HTMLHelper RadioButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

I'm new in .net Family and i've been looking asp.net webpage and following the MVC tutorials

the problem is

I'm using LinQ to Sql (2005) model and C# and i need to put a radioButton to know if a date must be initialized or not

how do i do this using html helpers ??

Comment: you can find radiobuttonlist helper here: http://awesome.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide more information on what are you doing.
Assuming that you want to post some form with some input values with one of them a radioButton, you should have id for the radiobutton and in the action that processes output of this form just add something like

```
bool dateNeedsInit = form["dateInit"].Equals("true");
```

For more information on radiobutton see e.g. [this link](http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/05/03/tip-of-the-day-201-asp-net-mvc-radiobutton-controls/).